# MS Access 2007: Select Unique Records

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have a table with 3 columns. I need to return all records where the records are unique in the third column. I realize this has been well documented all over, but I'm struggling.

Table: cars

```
Make   Model   Color
----   -----   -----
Ford   Escort   Red
Ford   Taurus   Black
Chevy  Vista    Green
```

The query needs to return:

```
Make   Model   Color
----   -----   -----
Ford   Escort   Red
Chevy  Vista    Green
```

The, i.e. one of the Ford records.

This is what I've written but it does not work...

```
SELECT [cars].* 
FROM [cars] 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [cars].[Make] FROM [cars) b 
ON [cars].[Make] = b.[Make];
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM [cars] a
INNER JOIN (SELECT [cars].[Color] FROM [cars] GROUP BY [cars].[Color] HAVING COUNT(*)=1) b 
ON a.[Color] = b.[Color];
```

Comment: This query will retrieve all the records with Color Black as per ur question if i understood correctly..